# Check if apprequest exists Facebook API PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How can I check if an apprequest have been sent? The callback response is:

[image: From Facebook blog post]

Is there any way I can take the REQUEST id, and confirm that it has been sent to the recipients? I want to make sure, people don't simply interfere with the request callback function, and make it 'look like' they sent an invitation.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `/REQUEST_ID` with your app access token? If you get the same response then you know it is a valid request id.

Comment: I hope you are not planning on “rewarding” your users for the act of sending out requests in any way? Because that would be a violation of Platform Policies.

Comment: @CBroe, well yeah. I was, few points per invite. Is it also a violation, if you reward the user once the referral is completed? I.e a user invites another user, and he then signups, they both benefit from this referral?

Comment: The latter is allowed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Rewarding_Users/ for details.